# Get number of all queries on my mysql database in last hour?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to get all queries that are made in last hour on my wordpress database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enabled general log on mysql

details :

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log

After that, you can parse/digest the log or simply do a `grep` (linux).

If you not familiar with `grep`, you can look for log analyzer for mysql
(I sure there is, but doing a `grep` is much easier)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the update queries (only queries which did a modification to the data) with [Binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/binary-log.html) or update log (You will need to enable them)

Slow queries are again logged to the slow query logs.

I am not aware if mysql logs read only queries.

Hope this is of some help.